# Sending multipart/related content to SOAP service .NET Core

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asp.net-core

I'm trying to set the headers of my `HttpRequestMessage` for sending a `multipart/related` HTTP message to a SOAP service.

The headers need to look to something like this :

> multipart/related;boundary=MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_7B970E2B89C4446286DDFDBFF7F19581; type="application/xop+xml"; start="0.urn:uuid:4628599A1A934415B3EFB15A1888004B@ws.jboss.org>"; start-info="application/soap+xml"; action="urn:ihe:iti:2007:ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSet-b"

But I can't figure out how to set them up with my `HttpRequestMessage`.
Here's my code :

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
   var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
   {
        RequestUri = new Uri(Host),
        Method = HttpMethod.Post
   };
   var boundary = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   var bytes = new ByteArrayContent(doc);
   bytes.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
   var multi = new MultipartContent("related", boundary) {
         new StringContent(xml.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml"), 
         bytes
   };
   request.Content = multi;

   Log.Information(request.Headers.ToString());
   Log.Information(request.Content.Headers.ToString());
   Log.Information(request.Content.ToString());

   var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
   if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        throw new Exception($"Request resulted in status :{response.StatusCode}");                           
   var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
   using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
   {
        var soapResponse = XDocument.Load(sr);
        Log.Information("Soap response : " + soapResponse);
   }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using the WCF connected services to connect to a WCF/Soap Service?!

Comment: It is .NET Core and I'm not able to add the connected service with the wsdl of the service. It says that the URL in the wsdl is invalid or something like that.